# stringWithContentsOfURL not working with certain string

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have code similar to the following with a URL like this...  If I use the first *url, webpage will return null.  If I put this URL into a URL shortening system like bit.ly it does work and returns the pages HTML as a string.  I can only think I have invalid characters in my first *url?  Any ideas?

```
NSString *url =@"http://www.testurl.com/testing/testapp.aspx/app.detail/params.frames.y.tpl.uk.item.1.cm_scid.TB-test/left.html.|metadrill,html/walk.yah.ukHB?cm_re=LN-_-OnNow-_-TestOne";

//above *url does not work, one below does
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://bit.ly/shortened"];
NSString *webpage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to escape some characters in the first URL, as follows:

```
NSString *url =@"http://www.testurl.com/testing/testapp.aspx/app.detail/params.frames.y.tpl.uk.item.1.cm_scid.TB-test/left.html.|metadrill,html/walk.yah.ukHB?cm_re=LN-_-OnNow-_-TestOne";
NSString *escapedURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *webpage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL]];
```

The construction of the URL and its fetch will fail if the URL contains characters that aren't escaped properly (looking at your URL, it's probably the pipe (|), question mark, or underscore).

Comment: An "escaped" character is represented by the hex code that translates to the character, rather than the character itself. For example, in URLs a space is properly represented by its "escaped" hex representation %20. The % indicates to the server that a character is escaped, and the next two characters are treated as hex and converted on the server side back to the appropriate unescaped character. It's a way of transmitting unusual characters (pipes, etc.) reliably.